# EventSocket library is working with python3

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

I would like to ask you if the [EventSocket](https://pypi.org/project/eventsocket/) library is working with python3.
If not, is python3 support planned?

Best regards.

Comment: could you state which library you are asking about? A link to the library would be really helpful

Comment: @argo: Done, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from the author (
Alexandre Fiori)  that this is not yet planned.

Cheers